# I tried to get the 'location' from the below JSON, but it returns response 'nil'

Tags: ios, json, swift, get

I tried to get the `location` from the below JSON, but it returns response `nil`, can you check it once. Below URL gives the response, but I want to display location from below JSON.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4ytNy-Nv7")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil
    {
        print ("ERROR")
    }
    else
    {
        if let content = data
        {
            do
            {
                //Array
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                print(myJson)
                let val = myJson["Location"] as? NSDictionary
                print("val=\(val)")


            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Foundation` datatypes, such as `NSDictionary`, when they have native `Swift` counterparts. You also need to cast the `JSON` to an array of dictionaries. However, the problem that actually caused the issue was that `Location` is a `String` and not a dictionary.

```
guard let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [[String:Any]], let myJson = myJsonArray.first else {return}
print(myJson)
let val = myJson["Location"] as? String
print("val=\(val)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The root object of the JSON is clearly an **array of a dictionary** not *something* (`AnyObject`). The value for key `Location` is in the first object of the array

```
if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [[String:Any]], !myJson.isEmpty { // check also that the array is not empty
   print(myJson)
   let val = myJson[0] // get first object of the array
   let location = val["Location"] as? String ?? "n/a"
   print("location = \(location)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to download your data. Further more since your array has only one object, to access multiple locations you can iterate through the array objects

```
func downloadData(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4ytNy-Nv7")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [[String:Any]]
                    let object = myJson?[0]
                    if let location = object?["Location"] as? String{
                        print(location)
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this part :

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
```

Into :

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Then if your JSON only have one object try this to get the `Location` :

```
let obj = myJson[0]
let location = obj["Location"] as? String
print("Location \(location)")
```